# How to tell Sequelize to not insert if multiple rows already have the same value in multiple columns

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

Disclaimer: I'm a front end engineer all this is new to me.

Building a reporting service that schedules reports.

Using sequelize and postgress. I want to make sure that you cant have multiple entries with the same userId/email/cadence/siteId columns.

For example if user:9, email: me@gmail.com, cadence: weekly, siteId: 4 already exist in DB don't insert the same data gain.

To the best of my research I'm attempting to add constraints to the migration file which is as follows:

```
exports.shorthands = undefined;

exports.up = (pgm) => {
  pgm.createTable(
    'report',
    {
      id: 'id',
      site_id: { type: 'varchar(255)', notNull: true },
      report_name: { type: 'varchar(255)', notNull: true },
      user_email: { type: 'varchar(255)', notNull: true },
      portfolo_id: { type: 'varchar(40)' },
      cadence: { type: 'varchar(40)', notNull: true },
      user_id: { type: 'varchar(40)', notNull: true },
      createdAt: {
        type: 'timestamptz',
        notNull: true,
        default: pgm.func('current_timestamp'),
      },
      updatedAt: {
        type: 'timestamptz',
        notNull: true,
        default: pgm.func('current_timestamp'),
      },
    },
    {
      constraints: {
        unique: ['site_id', 'user_email', 'portfolo_id', 'cadence'],
      },
    },
  );
  pgm.createIndex('report', 'cadence');
  pgm.createIndex('report', 'user_id');
  pgm.createIndex('report', 'user_email');
};

exports.down = (pgm) => {
  pgm.dropTable('report');
};
```

everything loads up fine but I'm able to hit my endpoint over and over with the same payload.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the [findOrCreate() method](https://sequelize.org/api/v7/classes/model#findOrCreate).

Edit to add for further clarity: You would not use the findOrCreate() method in the migration that you've shared here, but instead in the code for the endpoint you have described hitting over and over.

Comment: Ah, coding. The magical world of constant face palming. Thank you! This will probably do what I want!